# How can I customize a table?

Tags: tables

I created this table in MS Office; how can I obtain this table in LaTeX?

[image]

This is the code I tried, the result wasn't that good in terms of centering cells and columns.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\noindent Table 1. Overshoots and undershoots of  ${\textrm{?}}_{syn},{\textrm{?}}_{syn},P_{dfig},I_{dr},I_{qr},I_{statcom}$ for all cases.
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.8in}|p{0.5in}|p{0.5in}|p{0.5in}|p{0.5in}|p{0.5in}|p{0.5in}|p{0.5in}|p{0.5in}|p{0.5in}|} \hline 
 & \multicolumn{3}{|p{1.5in}|}{Case 1 (No PSS/No STATCOM)} & \multicolumn{3}{|p{1.5in}|}{Case 2 (Only PSS)} & \multicolumn{3}{|p{1.5in}|}{Case 3 (PSS + STATCOM)} \\ \hline 
 & 0.2pu & 0.4pu & 0.6pu & 0.2pu & 0.4pu & 0.6pu & 0.2pu & 0.4pu & 0.6pu \\ \hline 
Delta${}_{1\ }$(pu) & +1446\% & instable & instable & +1616\% & +2300\% & +5126\% & +1000\% & +1396\% & +3130\% \\ \hline 
 & -2676\% &  &  & -1491\% & -2110\% & -4794\% & -438\% & -1474\% & -2937\% \\ \hline 
Delta${}_{2}$ (pu) & +70\% & instable & instable & +70\% & +63\% & +55.3\% & +31\% & +46\% & +40.26\% \\ \hline 
 & -117\% &  &  & -63\% & -54\% & -51.6\% & -17\% & -39\% & -31.46\% \\ \hline 
Delta${}_{3}$ (pu) & +61\% & instable & instable & +78\% & +68\% & +59.2\% & +29\% & +51\% & 43.6\% \\ \hline 
 & -121\% &  &  & -66\% & -49\% & -41.3\% & -10\% & -36\% & -27\% \\ \hline 
Omega${}_{1\ }$(pu) & +0.4\% & instable & instable & +0.3\% & +0.3\% & +0.3\% & +0.3\% & +0.3\% & 0.3\% \\ \hline 
 & -0.34\% &  &  & -0.23\% & -0.21\% & -0.22\% & -0.21\% & -0.21\% & -0.21\% \\ \hline 
Omega${}_{2\ }$(pu) & +0.6\% & instable & instable & +0.5\% & +0.5\% & +0.5\% & +0.5\% & +0.5\% & +0.5\% \\ \hline 
 & -0.54\% &  &  & -0.34\% & -0.37\% & -0.39\% & -0.33\% & -0.37\% & -0.41\% \\ \hline 
Omega${}_{3\ }$(pu) & +0.7 & instable & instable & +0.7\% & +0.7\% & +0.7\% & +0.7\% & +0.7\% & +0.7\% \\ \hline 
 & -0.54\% &  &  & -0.32\% & -0.3\% & -0.31\% & -0.31\% & -0.3\% & -0.34\% \\ \hline 
P${}_{dfig}$(pu) & +22\% & instable & instable & +27.4\% & +12.7\% & +7.9\% & +13.5\% & +6.5\% & +4.2\% \\ \hline 
 & -16.4\% &  &  & -15.1\% & -5.6\% & -3.66\% & -4\% & -4.4\% & -2.75\% \\ \hline 
I${}_{dr}$(pu) & +17\% & instable & instable & +9.7\% & +7.9\% & +5\% & +23\% & +19.8\% & +17\% \\ \hline 
 & Idr${}_{min}$ &  &  & Idr${}_{min}$ & Idr${}_{min}$ & Idr${}_{min}$ & Idr${}_{min}$ & Idr${}_{min}$ & Idr${}_{min}$ \\ \hline 
I${}_{qr}$(pu) & +56\% & instable & instable & +56.5\% & +19.3\% & +8.5\% & +60\% & +23\% & +12.46\% \\ \hline 
 & Iqr${}_{min}$ &  &  & Iqr${}_{min}$ & Iqr${}_{min}$ & Iqr${}_{min}$ & Iqr${}_{min}$ & Iqr${}_{min}$ & Iqr${}_{min}$ \\ \hline 
I${}_{statc}$(pu) & / & / & / & / & / & / & +598\% & +748\% & +717\% \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: You're right, it was my 1st question here and i forget to add the draft code at least. I'll edit the post.   Thank or the remark

Comment: You can start with lesson 8 of [learn latex](https://www.learnlatex.org/) in which you will learn the basics about tables. If this is not enough you can ask an specific question about your problem trying to reproduce this table in latex

Comment: Now you have three answers, so yo can accept one of them, which on the best way fulfill your expectation (by clicking check mark at the top left side of selected answer). Later, when you have sufficient height reputation, you can also upvote answers, which you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `booktabs` we can clean up the table. Use `\multirow` to span multiple rows and `\textcolor` to change the color.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, amsmath, multirow}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\tiny
\caption{Overshoots and undershoots of $\delta_\text{sym}, \omega_\text{syn}, P_\text{dfig}, I_\text{dr}, I_\text{qr}, I_\text{statcom}$ for all cases.\strut}
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{3}{c}{Case 1 (No PSS/No STATCOM)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Case 2 (Only PSS)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Case 3 (PSS + STATCOM)}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-10}
 & 0.2 pu & 0.4 pu & 0.6 pu & 0.2 pu & 0.4 pu & 0.6 pu & 0.2 pu & 0.4 pu & 0.6 pu \\
 \midrule 
 
\multirow{2}{*}{$\delta_1$ (pu)} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+1446\%} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textcolor{ForestGreen}{Instable}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textcolor{ForestGreen}{Instable}} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+1616\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+2300\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+5126\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+1000\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+1396\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+3130\%} \\  
 &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-2676\%} &  &  &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-1491\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-2110\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-4794\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-438\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-1474\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-2937\%} \\  
\midrule

\multirow{2}{*}{$\delta_2$ (pu)} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+70\%} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textcolor{ForestGreen}{Instable}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textcolor{ForestGreen}{Instable}} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+70\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+63\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+55.3\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+31\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+46\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+40.26\%} \\  
 &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-117\%} &  &  &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-63\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-54\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-51.6\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-17\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-39\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-31.46\%} \\  
 \midrule

\multirow{2}{*}{$\delta_3$ (pu)} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+61\%} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textcolor{ForestGreen}{Instable}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textcolor{ForestGreen}{Instable}} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+78\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+68\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+59.2\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+29\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+51\%} & \textcolor{ForestGreen}{+43.6\%} \\  
&\textcolor{BrickRed}{-121\%} &  &  &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-66\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-49\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-41.3\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-10\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-36\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-27\%} \\  
 \midrule

\multirow{2}{*}{$\omega_1$ (pu)} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+0.4\%} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textcolor{ForestGreen}{Instable}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textcolor{ForestGreen}{Instable}} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+0.3\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+0.3\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+0.3\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+0.3\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+0.3\%} & \textcolor{ForestGreen}{+0.3\%} \\  
 &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-0.34\%} &  &  &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-0.23\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-0.21\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-0.22\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-0.21\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-0.21\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-0.21\%} \\  
 \midrule

\multirow{2}{*}{$\omega_2$ (pu)} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+0.6\%} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textcolor{ForestGreen}{Instable}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textcolor{ForestGreen}{Instable}} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+0.5\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+0.5\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+0.5\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+0.5\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+0.5\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+0.5\%} \\  
 &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-0.54\%} &  &  &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-0.34\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-0.37\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-0.39\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-0.33\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-0.37\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-0.41\%} \\  
 \midrule

\multirow{2}{*}{$\omega_3$ (pu)} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+0.7\%} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textcolor{ForestGreen}{Instable}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textcolor{ForestGreen}{Instable}} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+0.7\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+0.7\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+0.7\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+0.7\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+0.7\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+0.7\%} \\  
 &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-0.54\%} &  &  &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-0.32\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-0.3\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-0.31\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-0.31\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-0.3\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-0.34\%} \\  
 \midrule

\multirow{2}{*}{$P_\text{dfig}$ (pu)} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+22\%} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textcolor{ForestGreen}{Instable}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textcolor{ForestGreen}{Instable}} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+27.4\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+12.7\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+7.9\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+13.5\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+6.5\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+4.2\%} \\  
 &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-16.4\%} &  &  &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-15.1\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-5.6\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-3.66\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-4\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-4.4\%} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{-2.75\%} \\  
 \midrule

\multirow{2}{*}{$I_\text{dr}$ (pu)} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+17\%} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textcolor{ForestGreen}{Instable}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textcolor{ForestGreen}{Instable}} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+9.7\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+7.9\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+5\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+23\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+19.8\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+17\%} \\  
 & \textcolor{BrickRed}{$I_{\text{dr}_\text{min}}$} &  &  & \textcolor{BrickRed}{$I_{\text{dr}_\text{min}}$} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{$I_{\text{dr}_\text{min}}$} &\textcolor{BrickRed}{$I_{\text{dr}_\text{min}}$} & \textcolor{BrickRed}{$I_{\text{dr}_\text{min}}$} & \textcolor{BrickRed}{$I_{\text{dr}_\text{min}}$} & \textcolor{BrickRed}{$I_{\text{dr}_\text{min}}$} \\  
 \midrule

\multirow{2}{*}{$I_\text{qr}$ (pu)} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+56\%} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textcolor{ForestGreen}{Instable}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textcolor{ForestGreen}{Instable}} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+56.5\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+19.3\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+8.5\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+60\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+23\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+12.46\%} \\  
 & \textcolor{BrickRed}{$I_{\text{qr}_\text{min}}$} &  &  & \textcolor{BrickRed}{$I_{\text{qr}_\text{min}}$} & \textcolor{BrickRed}{$I_{\text{qr}_\text{min}}$} & \textcolor{BrickRed}{$I_{\text{qr}_\text{min}}$} & \textcolor{BrickRed}{$I_{\text{qr}_\text{min}}$} & \textcolor{BrickRed}{$I_{\text{qr}_\text{min}}$} & \textcolor{BrickRed}{$I_{\text{qr}_\text{min}}$} \\  
 \midrule

$I_\text{statc}$ (pu) &--- &--- &--- &--- &--- &--- &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+598\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+748\%} &\textcolor{ForestGreen}{+717\%} \\  

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks alot @Dan for your great suggestion!

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to TEX.SE! I use package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) to achieve this. I really really recommand this package, and it's manual is also clear.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \caption{Overshoots and undershoots of  ${\delta}_{syn},{\omega}_{syn},P_{dfig},I_{dr},I_{qr},I_{statcom}$ for all cases.}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tblr}{
    cells                   =   {c},
    row{even}               =   {fg = red5},
    row{odd}                =   {fg = green6},
    row{1, 2, Z}            =   {fg = black},
    column{1}               =   {fg = black},
    cell{Z}{X-Z}            =   {fg = green6},
    vline{1, 2, 5, 8, 11}   =   {solid},
    vline{3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10}=   {2-Z}{solid},
    hline{odd}              =   {solid},
    hline{even}             =   {2, 3-Z}{solid},
    cell{1}{1}              =   {c = 1, r = 2}{c},
    cell{3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19}{1, 3, 4}  =   {c = 1, r = 2}{c},
    cell{1}{2, 5, 8}        =   {c = 3, r = 1}{c},
    hline{Z}                =   {solid},
}
    & Case 1 (No PSS/No STATCOM) & & &  {Case 2 (Only PSS)} & & & {Case 3 (PSS + STATCOM)} \\
    & 0.2pu & 0.4pu & 0.6pu & 0.2pu & 0.4pu & 0.6pu & 0.2pu & 0.4pu & 0.6pu \\
    Delta${}_{1\ }$(pu) & +1446\% & instable & instable & +1616\% & +2300\% & +5126\% & +1000\% & +1396\% & +3130\% \\
    & -2676\% &  &  & -1491\% & -2110\% & -4794\% & -438\% & -1474\% & -2937\% \\
    Delta${}_{2}$ (pu) & +70\% & instable & instable & +70\% & +63\% & +55.3\% & +31\% & +46\% & +40.26\% \\
    & -117\% &  &  & -63\% & -54\% & -51.6\% & -17\% & -39\% & -31.46\% \\
    Delta${}_{3}$ (pu) & +61\% & instable & instable & +78\% & +68\% & +59.2\% & +29\% & +51\% & 43.6\% \\
    & -121\% &  &  & -66\% & -49\% & -41.3\% & -10\% & -36\% & -27\% \\
    Omega${}_{1\ }$(pu) & +0.4\% & instable & instable & +0.3\% & +0.3\% & +0.3\% & +0.3\% & +0.3\% & 0.3\% \\
    & -0.34\% &  &  & -0.23\% & -0.21\% & -0.22\% & -0.21\% & -0.21\% & -0.21\% \\
    Omega${}_{2\ }$(pu) & +0.6\% & instable & instable & +0.5\% & +0.5\% & +0.5\% & +0.5\% & +0.5\% & +0.5\% \\
    & -0.54\% &  &  & -0.34\% & -0.37\% & -0.39\% & -0.33\% & -0.37\% & -0.41\% \\
    Omega${}_{3\ }$(pu) & +0.7 & instable & instable & +0.7\% & +0.7\% & +0.7\% & +0.7\% & +0.7\% & +0.7\% \\
    & -0.54\% &  &  & -0.32\% & -0.3\% & -0.31\% & -0.31\% & -0.3\% & -0.34\% \\
    P${}_{dfig}$(pu) & +22\% & instable & instable & +27.4\% & +12.7\% & +7.9\% & +13.5\% & +6.5\% & +4.2\% \\
    & -16.4\% &  &  & -15.1\% & -5.6\% & -3.66\% & -4\% & -4.4\% & -2.75\% \\
    I${}_{dr}$(pu) & +17\% & instable & instable & +9.7\% & +7.9\% & +5\% & +23\% & +19.8\% & +17\% \\
    & Idr${}_{min}$ &  &  & Idr${}_{min}$ & Idr${}_{min}$ & Idr${}_{min}$ & Idr${}_{min}$ & Idr${}_{min}$ & Idr${}_{min}$ \\
    I${}_{qr}$(pu) & +56\% & instable & instable & +56.5\% & +19.3\% & +8.5\% & +60\% & +23\% & +12.46\% \\
    & Iqr${}_{min}$ &  &  & Iqr${}_{min}$ & Iqr${}_{min}$ & Iqr${}_{min}$ & Iqr${}_{min}$ & Iqr${}_{min}$ & Iqr${}_{min}$ \\
    I${}_{statc}$(pu) & / & / & / & / & / & / & +598\% & +748\% & +717\% \\
\end{tblr}}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As we can see, it used a key-value option list to manage the style of this table, and in the body of table, you can just write your content without caring of color, multirow and so on.

Comment: Good contribution. Thanks alot. Syvshc

Answer (score 3):

A variation of attractive @Syvshc answer. Differences are:

- removed is table scaling, instead is prescribed smaller font size
- for columns with numbers are used `S` columns (enabled by `si` column options defined in Tblr Library `siunitx`)
- preamble is more concise and shorter
- indices, which are not variables are in up shape
- percent symbols written only in column headers

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \sisetup{table-format=-4.2,
             group-minimum-digits=4,
             minimum-decimal-digits=2,
             round-mode = figures,
             round-precision = 2}
\caption{Overshoots and undershoots of  ${\delta}_{\mathrm{syn}},{\omega}_{\mathrm{syn}},P_{\mathrm{dfig}},I_{\mathrm{dr}},I_{\mathrm{qr}},I_{\mathrm{statcom}}$ for all cases.}
\label{tab:sumarry}

\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             row{odd} = {fg=teal},
            row{even} = {fg=red},
              colspec = {Q[l,fg=black] Q[c,si] *{2}{Q[c, fg=teal]} *{6}{Q[c,si]}},
            column{1} = {fg = black},
         cell{Z}{X-Z} = {fg = green6},
           cell{1}{1} = {c = 1, r = 2}{c},
            cell{3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19}{1,3,4} = {c=1, r=2}{c},
      cell{1}{2,5,8} = {c=3, r=1}{c},
              colsep = {4pt},
          row{1,2,Z} = {fg = black},
                rows = {font=\footnotesize},
            }
    &   {{{Case 1 (No PSS/No STATCOM)}}} & &
        &   {{{Case 2 (Only PSS)}}} & &
            &   {{{Case 3 (PSS + STATCOM)}}}   &   &   \\
    & {{{0.2pu (\%)}}}
        & {{{0.4pu}}}
            & {{{0.6pu}}}
                & {{{0.2pu (\%)}}}
                    & {{{0.4pu (\%)}}}
                        & {{{0.6pu (\%)}}}
                            & {{{0.2pu (\%)}}}
                                & {{{0.4pu (\%)}}}
                                        & {{{0.6pu (\%)}}}   \\
Delta\textsubscript{1} (pu)
    & +1446 & \SetCell[r=2]{c}    instable
                & \SetCell[r=2]{c}    instable
                    & +1616 & +2300 & +5126 & +1000 & +1396 & +3130 \\
    & -2676 &  &  & -1491 & -2110 & -4794 & -438 & -1474 & -2937 \\
Delta\textsubscript{2} (pu)
    & +70 & instable & instable & +70 & +63 & +55.3 & +31 & +46 & +40.26 \\
    & -117 &  &  & -63 & -54 & -51.6 & -17 & -39 & -31.46 \\
Delta\textsubscript{3} (pu)
    & +61 & instable & instable & +78 & +68 & +59.2 & +29 & +51 & 43.6 \\
    & -121 &  &  & -66 & -49 & -41.3 & -10 & -36 & -27 \\
Omega\textsubscript{1} (pu)
    & +0.4 & instable & instable & +0.3 & +0.3 & +0.3 & +0.3 & +0.3 & 0.3 \\
    & -0.34 &  &  & -0.23 & -0.21 & -0.22 & -0.21 & -0.21 & -0.21 \\
Omega\textsubscript{2} (pu)
    & +0.6 & instable & instable & +0.5 & +0.5 & +0.5 & +0.5 & +0.5 & +0.5 \\
    & -0.54 &  &  & -0.34 & -0.37 & -0.39 & -0.33 & -0.37 & -0.41 \\
Omega\textsubscript{3} (pu)
    & +0.7 & instable & instable & +0.7 & +0.7 & +0.7 & +0.7 & +0.7 & +0.7 \\
    & -0.54 &  &  & -0.32 & -0.3 & -0.31 & -0.31 & -0.3 & -0.34 \\
P\textsubscript{dfig} (pu)
    & +22 & instable & instable & +27.4 & +12.7 & +7.9 & +13.5 & +6.5 & +4.2 \\
    & -16.4 &  &  & -15.1 & -5.6 & -3.66 & -4 & -4.4 & -2.75 \\
I\textsubscript{dr} (pu)
    & +17 & instable & instable & +9.7 & +7.9 & +5 & +23 & +19.8 & +17 \\
    & {{{Idr\textsubscript{min} }}} &  &  & {{{Idr\textsubscript{min} }}} & {{{Idr\textsubscript{min} }}} & {{{Idr\textsubscript{min} }}} & {{{Idr\textsubscript{min} }}} & {{{Idr\textsubscript{min} }}} & {{{Idr\textsubscript{min} }}} \\
I\textsubscript{qr} (pu)
    & +56 & instable & instable & +56.5 & +19.3 & +8.5 & +60 & +23 & +12.46 \\
    & {{{Iqr\textsubscript{min} }}} &  &  & {{{Iqr\textsubscript{min} }}} & {{{Iqr\textsubscript{min} }}} & {{{Iqr\textsubscript{min} }}} & {{{Iqr\textsubscript{min} }}} & {{{Iqr\textsubscript{min} }}} & {{{Iqr\textsubscript{min} }}} \\
I\textsubscript{statc} (pu)
    & {{{--}}} & -- & -- & {{{--}}} & {{{--}}} & {{{--}}} & +598 & +748 & +717 \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice varation! I didn't notice the content of this table, just wrote the style :)

Comment: Very interesting variation @Zarko